# How can I copy ALL the attributes and styling from one svg to another svg using js please?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

The following code will copy ONE attribute: 'fill-rule' from svg(external svg) to snap paper(internal svg). How can I copy ALL the attributes and syling from one svg to another svg  please?
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
s1.attr("fill-rule", svg.node.getAttribute("fill-rule"));
```

Edit: If I use Roberts code, why this doesn't copy the attrs from svg to s1?:

```
s1.attr(attrs.item(i).svg);
```

live:
http://jsbin.com/geyog/5/edit

Comment: Because s1.attr takes two arguments to set a value, you're using it as a getter.

Comment: @ Robert. Do you mean something like: s1.attr("*", attrs.item(i).svg);

Comment: No I don't. You need to research the arguments attr takes.

Comment: @ Robert. Here I found this info: Arguments

name (DOMString)
required
The name of the attribute to
create or alter.

value (DOMString)
required
The string value for the
attribute.
But in this case I don't know the name of the attr to be created. So what should I do?

Comment: The name of the attribute is the nodeName property I provided in my answer. If you do some research you might find the other property you need too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an attributes property in the DOM

if you had

```
<svg id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%"/>
```

you can do this...

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
for (var i=0, attrs=svg.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    s1.attr(attrs.item(i).nodeName, attrs.item(i).value);
}
```

presumably in your case it would be

```
var svg = svg.node;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ Robert.How can I copy those attributes to s1 instead of alerting them please ?: http://jsbin.com/geyog/4/edit

Comment: @ Robert.I did some research and found that I need to have a pair of a nodename and a value so I need to add:  alert(attrs.item(i).value; to get the values for those node names but still cannot find a way to append those into the snap paer, s1. Could you please help with that?!

Comment: Thank you Robert. Last night I was playing with it after I asked you and then figured out your updated answer after finding the difference between snap attr and js attribute. Thanks for making me do it by myself and learn!